# How do I reference Rails in a gem I'm making?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm making a gem for Rails. I need access to the ApplicationController because I'll toy with it. Absolutely nothing online gives information about what to do with `gemspec` and then somehow manage to get Rails accessible in my gem.

I imagine the goal is eventually to be able to talk to Rails like:

```
module Rails
  module ActionController
    #code
  end
end
```

Comment: If you are developing a gem exclusively for Rails I strongly recommend you generate the initial scaffold using `rails plugin new gem_name`. There's a ton of info on developing rails plugins.

Comment: @nicooga Ok. I imagine once I get it working that way I should focus on making the plugin a gem, right?

Comment: The plugin generator generates the gemspec :).

Comment: Ah, so it is as simple as getting it up on rubygems?

Comment: Yes, it also generates a Rakefile with some useful commands like `release`

Comment: Thanks, @nicooga. I'll check it out. Hopefully I could go from there. If you include this information in an Answer below, I'll gladly mark it as the answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing a gem exclusively for Rails I strongly recommend you generate the initial scaffold using rails plugin new gem_name. There's a ton of info on developing rails plugins.

The initial structure generated looks like this:

```
gem_name
  gem_name.gemspec
  lib/
    gem_name.rb
    gem_name/
      version.rb
      engine.rb # if generated using --mountable
```

The whole rails environment becomes available [*edit: after your gem is loaded*] so extending `ApplicationController` can be done like this:

```
# lib/gem_name.rb
require 'gem_name/controller_extensions'
module GemName
end

# lib/gem_name/controller_extensions.rb
module GemName::ControllerExtensions
  # bleh
end

# dummy_application/app/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include GemName::ControllerExtensions
end
```

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348332/how-can-i-extend-applicationcontroller-in-a-gem).

Comment: So, if I had access to ApplicationController, my gem would basically be finished. However, with what you wrote above and my code in the `module GemName::ControllerExtensions` (I appropriately swapped out GemName with my own). I get an error though when I try to run `rails s` in the dummy app within the test folder supplied. The error is: `/Path/To/Gem/lib/gem/controller_extension.rb:15:in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)`.

Comment: I see. Is there anyway where I wouldn't have to include it like you did? I've tested, and confirmed that what you have there does indeed work :)