# How to extend ApplicationController in my gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

For example, I want to stop render layout for all actions. I can write in ApplicationController this code and its work:

```
layout :false
```

So, I want to create gem, which add this functionality.
I try this code in lib of my gem:

```
module MyLayout
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end

  class ApplicationLayoutController < ApplicationController
    layout :false
  end
end
```

and this:

```
module MyLayout
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end

  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout :false
  end
end
```

But it is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extend ApplicationController in a gem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348332/how-can-i-extend-applicationcontroller-in-a-gem)

Answer (score 1):

You are just defining your own `ApplicationController` class. It lives in your module, like so: `MyLayout::ApplicationController`. It doesn't affect the app that uses them gem by just existing.

If you want to provide the wanted functionality for users of your gem, you have a couple of options.

The "nicest" is probably to provide your own subclass of `ActionController::Base` and instruct your users to inherit from that:

```
module MyLayout
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end

  class ApplicationLayoutController < ApplicationController
    layout :false
  end
end

# When using your gem

class MyController < MyLayout::ApplicationLayoutController
  # stuff
end
```

Another way is to provide a module, which runs `layout: false` when included:

```
module MyLayout
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end

  module MyLayoutController
    def self.included(base)
      base.layout(:false)
    end
  end
end

# When using your gem

class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyLayoutController
end
```

Another way, but probably not very advisable, is to monkey patch `ActionController::Base`.